# Leaky p trap, no bevel at connection point

Tags: leak, p-trap

The p trap in my kitchen sink started leaking at the rear connection point. When I unscrewed it to see what was going on, there was no bevel on either end of the connection. I don’t know how the seal was ever watertight in the first place, and it doesn’t look like something I could easily slide a washer onto (I think there isn’t supposed to be a washer at this connection anyway…). I’m not sure what to do to fix it. Any ideas?

[image: ptrap connection]

Comment: Hard to tell from the pic but it looks like someone used a 90 degree elbow without a beveled rim. You'll probably just need to pick up and install one with the correct style rim.

Comment: Ahh okay, that was my assumption but was hoping to not have to undo any more non-leaking connections. Thanks for the response!

Comment: The top part looks like a tailpiece flange. Definitely the wrong part for that p trap.

Comment: A tailpiece flange requires a soft seal with L-shaped cross section which fits inside the tailpiece and fits between the sink drain and the plastic flat of the tailpiece. One of those  would probably make this joint leak free, but it is probably better to just get a new trap consisting of both parts.

Comment: Thanks, Jim! I tried an L-shape soft seal and it helped, but a few drops were still getting through. I tried a bevel shaped seal next, and so far that is working. We'll see if it lasts!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

You need a wall bend tube It has the bevel designed for slip nut.

What you have is a Waste Arm.

m[image]

It is designed with flat mating surface that attaches to bottom of drain basket.

Comment: This is exactly what was happening. I'm assuming the waste arm was used because of its length, the 7" wall tube doesn't reach the sink connectors. As an experiment, I tried adding a beveled rubber washer between the p-trap and the waste arm, and so far that seal has held firm. We'll see how long it lasts.

Comment: You may need to extend the pipe from the wall

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear the trap is supposed to have a bevel at that joint. Maybe so or maybe not. It may be that there are two flat faces that the large plastic nut clamps together. Look online at pics, or go to a big box store and look at stock.

EDIT

The one in the video below seems flat but cannot really tell, but it could be that the flat ones need a soft flat seal between the two flat surfaces.
https://youtu.be/YYZj-eGdYl8

EDIT'

I now think there is supposed to be a cone or bevel on the end of the part that fits into the curved part of the trap.

Comment: All the photos and how-tos I came across prior to posting here indicated a bevel was required for a tight seal, and unfortunately nothing I found addressed getting a water tight seal with two flat surfaces.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Doesn't appear that you have two flat surfaces. It appears that the top one is flat and the bottom one is beveled.

Comment: @honeyDo, I think it’s a distortion from the water on the right side of that bottom pipe. It is actually flat, no bevel.